# PHP executes longer than max_execution_time... sometimes

Tags: php, apache, curl, timeout

I have a PHP class, once called, sets the time limit to 60 seconds. The only special thing about this class is that it uses curl_multi_exec().

```
set_time_limit(60);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
```

The problem is that under Apache's /server-status page, this page and another one that uses single threaded curl run past their max_execution_time and reach up to 200 seconds, sometimes!

What am I missing? Is there a way to setup Apache to terminate scripts (or even connections) running for longer than say 90 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration directive `max_execution_time` only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

Because curl requests fall under this category, time spent waiting for a request to complete will not be counted.  You should set the curl setting `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to a lower value, or monitor the time spent in executing your script yourself.

Comment: That makes sense. I just checked that function, and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is 15 and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is 12, that doesn't add up to 200 seconds.

Comment: @Amer Presumably you have more than one request, from what you're saying.  Those values will be per-request.

Comment: I'm using multi curl, so they're fired at the same time.

Comment: @Amer Depending on how many requests you're sending, it seems possible that there's some kind of "maximum simultaneous request" limit being hit.

Comment: Well, my TCP connections limit is 1000 and I barely have 100 simultaneously established connections at once. I'm baffled by this problem. How does one go about debugging curl requests timing?

Comment: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT combined with the way the function was called seems to be the cause of the problem. I believe it's solved now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! When you set that configuration, the ticker resets itself, example:

```
sleep(10);
set_time_limit(20);
sleep(10);
set_time_limit(5);
sleep(10); // dies after 5 seconds
```

Total running time is ~30s.

With regards to `curl_exec_multi`, you can set the CURL timeout option instead of the PHP one. This depends on who would rather die in your opinion - the curl connection, or the full request.

Comment: I'm adding some time counters to investigate that. Thanks.